# Mysql: how to get unique values in column that can have a value or 0

Tags: mysql

Mysql

on a simple table (all integers)
A B C

I want to query all rows where C is a distinct number or 0
for example:

`0 1 4
4 5 6
6 5 0
5 6 0
7 5 4
8 5 6
9 5 0`

Should give:

`0 1 4
4 5 6
6 5 0
5 6 0
9 5 0`

rows:

`7 5 4
8 5 6`

didnt match because in col C  4 and 6 already appear.
All the C=0 columns should appear.

Whats the best way to do a query that does distinct C or C=0 ?
the results order doesn't matter.

Comment: `the results order doesn't matter` - Odd

Comment: What determines the order of the rows?

Comment: Is it significant that 014 was chosen instead of 754? Would it be ok to return 754 and drop 014?

Comment: @MichaelGreen yes its ok to return 754 and drop 014

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz there is a simple key A B C

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ  I need one sample of each C if C is non zero it doesnt matter which. and all the C with 0.  Nothing odd about it

Comment: Is A,B,C unique (at least for C=0) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE C=0 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE C<>0 GROUP BY C;
```

The caveat here is that you have no control on which row will be returned from each set of rows that have the same values of "C"

```
mysql> desc mytable;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| b     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| c     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    0 |    1 |    4 |
|    4 |    5 |    6 |
|    6 |    5 |    0 |
|    5 |    6 |    0 |
|    7 |    5 |    4 |
|    8 |    5 |    6 |
|    9 |    5 |    0 |
+------+------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE C=0 
    -> UNION ALL
    -> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE C<>0 GROUP BY C;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    6 |    5 |    0 |
|    5 |    6 |    0 |
|    9 |    5 |    0 |
|    0 |    1 |    4 |
|    4 |    5 |    6 |
+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Since this is improper use of `GROUP BY`, you may need to set a flag having to do with "only full group by".

Answer (score 1):

If (A,B,C) is unique, at least for C=0.

```
select      min(a)                                      as a
           ,substr(min(concat(lpad(a,10,'0'),b)),11)    as b
           ,c                                           as c

from        mytable

group by    case c when 0 then a end
           ,case c when 0 then b end 
           ,c   

order by    a,b,c
```

else -

```
select a,b,c from mytable where c = 0

union all

select      min(a)                                      as a
           ,substr(min(concat(lpad(a,10,'0'),b)),11)    as b
           ,c                                           as c

from        mytable

where       coalesce(c,-1) <> 0

group by    c   

order by    a,b,c
```

--

```
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 4 |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
+---+---+---+
| 5 | 6 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 6 | 5 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 9 | 5 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
```